# Merging Dataframes With Some Matching Columns Names Results in Duplicate Columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two data frames with some overlapping columns that I am trying to merge for a given `Symbol` and `Date`. But when I do, rather than fill the missing data, new columns with suffixes are being added.

`df1`

```
  Investor     Date   Name Symbol  Price  Amount  Income
0     Mike  2019 Q4  A Inc    AAA    NaN     100     NaN
1     Bill  2019 Q4  C Inc    CCC    NaN     200     NaN
2     John  2018 Q4  A Inc    AAA    NaN     200     NaN
3     Faye  2018 Q4  D Inc    DDD    NaN     300     NaN
4      Joe  2019 Q2  A Inc    AAA    NaN     300     NaN
5     Hank  2019 Q2  S Inc    SSS    NaN     100     NaN
```

`df2`

```
      Date   Name Symbol  Price  Income
0  2019 Q4  A Inc    AAA      5      10
1  2019 Q4  B Inc    BBB      3      20
2  2019 Q4  C Inc    CCC     33      30
3  2019 Q4  D Inc    DDD     30      40
4  2018 Q4  A Inc    AAA     23      20
5  2018 Q4  B Inc    BBB      4      30
6  2018 Q4  C Inc    CCC    136      40
7  2018 Q4  D Inc    DDD      6      50
8  2018 Q4  E Inc    EEE      1      90
```

I want my output to look like:

```
  Investor     Date   Name Symbol  Price  Amount  Income
0     Mike  2019 Q4  A Inc    AAA    5.0     100    10.0
1     Bill  2019 Q4  C Inc    CCC   33.0     200    30.0
2     John  2018 Q4  A Inc    AAA   23.0     200    20.0
3     Faye  2018 Q4  D Inc    DDD    6.0     300    50.0
4      Joe  2019 Q2  A Inc    AAA    NaN     300     NaN
5     Hank  2019 Q2  S Inc    SSS    NaN     100     NaN
```

But when I do `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Symbol'], how='left')`, I get:

```
  Investor     Date Name_x Symbol  ...  Income_x  Name_y  Price_y Income_y
0     Mike  2019 Q4  A Inc    AAA  ...       NaN   A Inc      5.0     10.0
1     Bill  2019 Q4  C Inc    CCC  ...       NaN   C Inc     33.0     30.0
2     John  2018 Q4  A Inc    AAA  ...       NaN   A Inc     23.0     20.0
3     Faye  2018 Q4  D Inc    DDD  ...       NaN   D Inc      6.0     50.0
4      Joe  2019 Q2  A Inc    AAA  ...       NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
5     Hank  2019 Q2  S Inc    SSS  ...       NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
df1 = `df1 = {'Investor': {0: 'Mike', 1: 'Bill', 2: 'John', 3: 'Faye', 4: 'Joe', 5: 'Hank'}, 'Date': {0: '2019 Q4', 1: '2019 Q4', 2: '2018 Q4', 3: '2018 Q4', 4: '2019 Q2', 5: '2019 Q2'}, 'Name': {0: 'A Inc', 1: 'C Inc', 2: 'A Inc', 3: 'D Inc', 4: 'A Inc', 5: 'S Inc'}, 'Symbol': {0: 'AAA', 1: 'CCC', 2: 'AAA', 3: 'DDD', 4: 'AAA', 5: 'SSS'}, 'Price': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}, 'Amount': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 200, 3: 300, 4: 300, 5: 100}, 'Income': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}}`
df2 = {'Date': {0: '2019 Q4', 1: '2019 Q4', 2: '2019 Q4', 3: '2019 Q4', 4: '2018 Q4', 5: '2018 Q4', 6: '2018 Q4', 7: '2018 Q4', 8: '2018 Q4'}, 'Name': {0: 'A Inc', 1: 'B Inc', 2: 'C Inc', 3: 'D Inc', 4: 'A Inc', 5: 'B Inc', 6: 'C Inc', 7: 'D Inc', 8: 'E Inc'}, 'Symbol': {0: 'AAA', 1: 'BBB', 2: 'CCC', 3: 'DDD', 4: 'AAA', 5: 'BBB', 6: 'CCC', 7: 'DDD', 8: 'EEE'}, 'Price': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 33, 3: 30, 4: 23, 5: 4, 6: 136, 7: 6, 8: 1}, 'Income': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 20, 5: 30, 6: 40, 7: 50, 8: 90}}
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Symbol'], how='left')
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have `Name, Income, Price` on both dataframes. If you don't want the duplicates, you should then select those columns you want:

```
(df1[['Investor', 'Name', 'Date','Symbol','Amount']]
   .merge(df2.drop('Name', axis=1),
          on=['Date','Symbol'],
          how='left')
)
```

Output:

```
  Investor   Name     Date Symbol  Amount  Price  Income
0     Mike  A Inc  2019 Q4    AAA     100    5.0    10.0
1     Bill  C Inc  2019 Q4    CCC     200   33.0    30.0
2     John  A Inc  2018 Q4    AAA     200   23.0    20.0
3     Faye  D Inc  2018 Q4    DDD     300    6.0    50.0
4      Joe  A Inc  2019 Q2    AAA     300    NaN     NaN
5     Hank  S Inc  2019 Q2    SSS     100    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: So I need to specify every single column I want to keep from `df1` by listing it in `(df1[['Investor', 'Name', 'Date','Symbol','Amount']]`?

Comment: Yes, your you can drop the columns, similar to `df2.drop(['Name'], axis=1)`.

Comment: There's no way to keep every column without explicitly listing it? Basically there are no columns in `df1` that don't exist in `df2`, and I would like to keep all columns in `df1`—just fill missing values if they exist in `df2`.